# Integration of TestLink and JIRA

Tags: configuration, integration, jira, testlink

I am trying to integrate jira (6.3.15) with testlink (1.9.6). For that, I use in the following configuration in TestLink:

```
<issuetracker>
<dbhost>localhost</dbhost>
<dbname>jiradb</dbname>
<dbtype>mysql</dbtype>
<dbuser>jirauser</dbuser>
<dbpassword>jirauser</dbpassword>
<uriview>http://localhost:8080/browse/</uriview>
<uricreate>http://localhost:8080/secure/CreateIssue.jspa</uricreate>
</issuetracker>
```

As I save the configuration, I don't receive any error messages. When I switch to the Test Execution and select any test case, I receive a message: "Attention Please: Something is preventing connection to Bug Tracking System, and is going to create performance issues. Please contact your TestLink Administrator".

If the configuration was erronous or if further steps are necessary, please advise, how to proceed. Thank you.

Comment: Any errors in the logs?

Comment: Sorry for the later reply: which logs do you mean? I checked the application usage logs, there are no errors, just tracking the user actions. I assume, there might be some other logs, which I haven't detected yet.

Comment: I don't know TestLink. You sure there are no other lines of the error message? Does it work if you use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost"?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `localhost/127.0.0.1`, try using `0.0.0.0` instead which will allow `TestLink` to reach entire ip range of local machine.

Also check if your firewall allows for `TestLink` to have `inbound` and `outbound` connections.